# error when trying to send email using smtp 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

trying to send a password recovery email using the smpt protocol in c# and for some reason I can't seem to get it right. I will highly appreciate it of someone could help.
This is what I was relying [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail). And Here's the code:

```
enter cpublic void sendEmailWithPass( string username , string email , string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("xxx", "xxx");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress(email, "CLIENT!");
            const string fromPassword = "xxx";
            string subject = "recover password";
            string body = "heloo! \n according to your request your password is: \n " + password;
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            { Subject = subject, Body = body })
            { smtp.Send(message); }
            SendMessage("&answerForgotRequest&true!");
        }
        catch
        {
            SendMessage("&answerForgotRequest&failed!");
        }            
    }
```

in addition, this is the line which corresponds to the error

```
 public void answerServer(string message)
    {
        string ans = message.Split('&')[2];

 if (ans.StartsWith("failed!"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("an error was occured while trying sending the mail");
        }
```

]

Comment: @Michael Randall, I have looked at the other question and still did not manage to make it work

Comment: Past your error

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: No we will need why its failed, how does it tell you its failed, this is what we need to know. what does it return

Comment: @MichaelRandall I don't know what you are asking for, I put the code of how I try to put the email, and the condition where it sends me that there was an error sending the email. I'm really having a hard time

Comment: @JohnathanHershkovich you should catch your exception ```catch (Exception e)``` then you can actually see what your error is. The exception will give you more information, with which maybe we can help you.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that I am running the program and when I try to recover the password of some random user, a window pops up displaying the error message saying "an error has occurred while trying sending the email

Comment: "an error has occurred while trying sending the email" does not give any indication of what the error was.

Comment: How can I know what the error is? I'm sorry about all my dumb questions I'm just really struggling with it. It does not display any error message other than tha t

Comment: ok so I opened te Error List Window on visual studio and this is what it returned: Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll

Comment: ```catch (Exception e) { var whatWeNeedToHelpYou = e.InnerException; }```

Comment: @Jerry Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll

Comment: That is what threw the exception, not the exception itself. When you wrap your code in try/catch blocks and throw the exception away it is very difficult to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are struggling with this, you need to at least try to catch the `exception`, no-one can help you as you are just throwing it away:

```
try
{
    // email code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // breakpoint this line (yes look up online how to do it)
    MessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString());
    // write it to file if you need to
    //File.WriteAllText("someFileName.Txt",Ex.ToString() );
}
```

Then when you have an actual exception, please paste it (or ask a new question) so we know what's happening.

You might want to have a look at these too:

[Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/exception-handling)

[Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017)